# How to select an item from a drop down menu on a website that's coded with an html input text object?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, automation, autocomplete

I'm trying to build a Chrome Extension that autofills a website form. The form has several drop down menus. However, these are not coded with the HTML select object. Instead, they're coded with the HTML input text object (see the attached photo) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FynG.png).

I'd like to build functionality that mirrors selectedIndex and select one of the drop down menu items.

Is this possible?

I've tried 3 things:

I've used .execCommand to mimic the user typing into the input box to narrow down the number of drop downs that appear. This isn't a complete solution because the user must still click on the drop down menu.

I've used .innerHTML and similar methods to change the websites HTML, so that it matches the output of when a user selects an option from the drop down menu. This makes the website look like the user has selected an option, but it doesn't full work either. As soon as the user clicks outside of the input field, the field revers back to being empty (maybe the form is refreshing?)

I've explored using Selenium, but I don't think it makes much sense here. I'm trying to build a Chrome Extension for other users, rather than automate testing.

Comment: What's the URL of the website?

Comment: It's a clothing resale website -- https://www.depop.com/products/create/